# pass function as parameter swift

Tags: swift

I want to pass

self?.present(mainvc, animated: true)

as a parameter into a function.

The resulting type, however, is void.

So how can I pass it as a parameter into another function?

Answer (score 1):

in the receiving class you might do this:

```
private var myfunc : Func?

func set(_func: @escaping Func) {
    self.myfunc = _func
    self.myfunc?()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define a Closure that matches the function definition.

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (UIViewController, Bool, (() -> Void)?) -> Void
```

Then declare a function that takes this Closure as a parameter

```
func yourFunction(completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

}
```

Before calling "yourFunction" you need to make sure that you unwrap self

```
guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
```

Then pass "present" function to "yourFunction"

```
strongSelf.yourFunction(completionHandler: present)
```